# Batch Apex/Trigger for Rollup the data with M-D Relation

Tags: apex, trigger, batch

We have a parent `Account` record "Test ABC" and child `Accounts` record "Test X" and "Test Y".

We have a Child object(Custom Object) `Child__c`. It is Master detail relation with `Account`Object.

Requirement is : if the Account's `child__c` object's records 'Jan month' data is updated.it should updated the "Parent Account related child__c object 'Jan month' data".

For example:

```
Parent Account: Test ABC (Having Child__c) - Sum (Test X + Test Y)
    Child Account:   Test X (Having Child__c) - Sum (Test 1 + Test 2) 
                               Test 1 (Having Child__c)
                               Test 2 (Having Child__c)
                     Test Y (Having Child__c) Sum (Test 3 + Test 4) 
                               Test 3 (Having Child__c)
                               Test 4 (Having Child__c)
```

if we update the child record(Jan month field) of the Test X(Account) and Test Y(Account).

Sum X+Y child record data(Jan Month) = Test ABC child record(Jan Month).

Tried Code:

```
public class AccountDataHelper{

public static void updateChildRecords(Map<Id, Account_Financial_Data__c> newMap){

    List<Account_Financial_Data__c> assetTagList = new List<Account_Financial_Data__c>();
    Map<Id, Account_Financial_Data__c> assetTagMap = new Map<Id, Account_Financial_Data__c>();

    for(Account_Financial_Data__c  assetTag : newMap.values()){

       if(assetTag.Account_Reference__c!= null){
          assetTagMap.put(assetTag.Id, assetTag); 
       }   
    }


        assetTagList = [SELECT Id, 
                               X1_del__c,
                               Account_Reference__c
                        FROM Account_Financial_Data__c 
                        WHERE Account_Reference__c IN: assetTagMap.keySet()];

        for(Account_Financial_Data__c  assetTag : assetTagList){
            if(assetTagMap.containsKey(assetTag.Account_Reference__c))

               assetTag.X1_del__c = assetTagMap.get(assetTag.Account_Reference__c).X1_del__c;
               system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'+assetTag.X1_del__c);
        }


           update assetTagList;

}
```

Comment: If your two object are in a Master-Detail relationship, is there a reason why you're trying to use a trigger here instead of a rollup summary field? Also, the relationship you're describing is confusing. Unless you are using a junction object, if `Child__c` is the child (or in other words, the 'detail' of the master-detail relationship), then `Child__c` can only point to one `Account` record. If `Child__c` is actually the parent (or 'Master') record in the relationship, that is extremely confusing, and you should probably [edit] your question to change that so it doesn't confuse other people.

Comment: Updated the requirement with clear explanation. Please check once. Thanks